# Adding Cancel Button to Javascript Alert

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my Javascript Alert:

```
<script>
function showMessage() {
    setTimeout(function() {
alert("alert");
}, 100);
}
</script>
```

When a user visits a page, a window pops up that says "alert" and it only has the "Ok" button. When it is clicked, the window goes away and displays the page under it. How do I add a "Cancel" button that has the same effect?

Answer (score 15):

Well you can use [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm)

```
confirm("alert");
```

The above returns `true` or `false`  based on the selection.

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of dialog boxes in JavaScript, (correct me if i'm wrong on this)

1. OK
2. OK and Cancel
3. Input/prompt.

   These JavaScript boxes cannot be customized.

   If you want a customized dialog box I suggest [jqueryui.com](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the confirm() to provide the cancel button.
below is a simple example to use **Cancel button**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    
        <div style="text-align: center;" xss=removed>
    <button  onclick="myFunction()"  >click Me</button>
    <div></div>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      confirm("Press a button!");
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using **alert** you need to use **confirm** for showing pop-up and based on the input to that pop-up you can tack your own action.

here i provide you a code snippet for the same

```html
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="showAlert()">Click Me!</button>
<p id="onOkClick" style="display:none">Ok</p>
<p id="onCancleClick" style="display:none">Cancle</p>
<script>
  function showAlert()
  {
    if(confirm("Hello I am Alert !"))
    {
   document.getElementById("onOkClick").style.display="block";
         document.getElementById("onCancleClick").style.display="none"
}
    else
    {
   document.getElementById("onOkClick").style.display="none";
         document.getElementById("onCancleClick").style.display="block"
}
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```